# Why inside Let while loop does not work SML

Tags: functional-programming, sml

i am new at Standard ML and i have a question , at the code below when
i run without the let-in structure , the code runs and gives result .When i put the the let-in
it shows syntax errors . Can anyone help me ?

```
fun findInd([],size, value , ans , l , h ) =  ~1
 |  findInd(lista ,size, value , ans , l , h) = 
 let 

    val midval = Real.round((real l + real h) / real 2) 
    val Nelem =  List.nth(lista,midval)

 in
    if l<=h then 
       if   Nelem <= value  then  findInd(lista,size,value,midval,midval+1,h )     
       else                       findInd(lista,size,value,ans,l,midval+(~1) ) 
   else
            ans 
 end;


let (* <-- this let gives the problem *)

    val s = 0
    val sum = ref s

    val maxlen = 0
    val maxlenptr = ref maxlen

    val counter_start = 0
    val counter = ref counter_start

    val arr = [1,5,~58,~1]
    val presum = [~53,~52,1,6]
    val minInd = [3,2,0,0

    while !counter < List.length(arr) do (
    sum := !sum + List.nth(arr,!counter);
    if !sum >=0 then  maxlenptr := !counter +  1 
    else
        let
        val ind = findInd(presum, List.length(arr) , s , ~1 ,0 , List.length(arr) + (~1) )
        val temp = List.nth(minInd,ind)
        in
        if ind <> ~1 andalso temp < counter_start then  maxlenptr := Int.max(!maxlenptr,counter_start + (~temp)) 
        else ()
        end;
        counter := !counter + 1
    );
    
        val m =  !maxlenptr
in (* <--- this in  *)
    m
end;
```

Comment: @sepp2k has already answered this, but it seems to me you're using a lot of procedural code to operate on lists, which are recursive data structures. I'm not sure what the code is supposed to achieve, but it strikes me that there is probably a much cleaner approach that is more "functional."

Comment: Yes you are right! I am trying to  write the ML code of this implementation and this code above was a part of my attempt -  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/longest-subarray-having-average-greater-than-or-equal-to-x/?fbclid=IwAR10CMr_nPn3M-WIcxAsh5kHAGhcuEWcKHutWJduhNnOFjOB3PlAhV9bgQs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of `let` is `let <declarations> in <expression>` and a while loop is not a declaration. You'll need to move it after the `in` (like you did with the `if`s in the other `let`s).